# Why does new HashMap<> produce an error in JDK 1.6 but not 1.7

Tags: java, generics

I noticed the following code works when compiling in eclipse with java spec 1.7 but does not work with 1.6.

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I'd like an explanation but this syntax and why it works for 1.7 .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243541/arraylist-vs-arraylistinteger

Comment: What's the point of this operator?

Comment: It's for type inference, but also at the same time telling the compiler "hey, this is not a raw type". You can see my answer in the post I linked to.

Comment: To cut down on visual noise, nothing more.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `new HashMap<>()` (called diamond syntax) is not allowed in JDK 1.6 simply because it was only introduced in Java SE 7.

Look for [Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) in **[Highlights of Technology Changes in Java SE 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html)**.

> I'd like an explanation but this syntax and why it works for 1.7 .

Here's that explanation (slightly adapted) from [Oracle itself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html):

> Compilers from releases prior to Java SE 7 are able to infer the actual type parameters of generic constructors, similar to generic methods. However, the compiler in Java SE 7 can infer the actual type parameters **of the generic class being instantiated if you use the diamond (`<>`)**. Consider the following example, which is valid for Java SE 7 and later:

```
class MyClass<X> {
  <T> MyClass(T t) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

```
MyClass<Integer> myObject = new MyClass<>("");
```

> In this example, the compiler **infers** the type `Integer` for the formal type parameter, `X`, of the generic class `MyClass<X>`. It **infers** the type `String` for the formal type parameter, `T`, of the constructor of this generic class.

Answer (score 14):

> In Java SE 7, you can substitute the parameterized type of the constructor with an empty set of type parameters (<>):

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

In Java SE 6 it had to be done this way:

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

[More details...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html)

Answer (score 4):

Because it's an enhancement of JDK 1.7 (the Diamond operator), before you have to specify the Generic types on the class and on the constructor `HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();`

Answer (score 2):

It is using the [diamond operator](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/7567) which was introduced in 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the same syntax you have used in JDK 1.7 For JDK 1.6